# Fetch Book field values on child level only once

Tags: 9

I'm working on a project where I use the core Book functionality to create my sites structure. I have three content types:

1. `Reader`
2. `Issue`
3. `Article`

Where `Issue` is a child of `Reader`, and `Article` is a child of `Issue`.

For this project I creates multiple custom modules to:

- Set books access permissions
- Change the books frontpage
- Set the books theme
- Add custom css settings per book

For all these modules I create a field in the `Reader` content type. But I want all its child nodes to also be affected by these field settings.

Now to do this I use the following code (example is taken from my custom css module):

```
if ($node->bundle() == 'reader') {
    //if reader
    $book = $node;
} else if ($node->bundle() == 'edition' || $node->bundle() == 'article') {
    //if edition or article
    //get parent book
    $book = Node::load($node->book['bid']);
}

//get textcolor from book
$textColor = $book->get('field_textcolor')->getValue()[0]['color'];
```

But since I'm doing this in all my module I thought...this is not good for performance because I'm using `Node::load` multiple times for the same thing. So I want to improve this method, if necessary.

So is there a way to either:

- Get the parent books field in a better way inside the modules?
- Or, create global variables from the parent Book field values, so I have to only fetch them once for every website visit/visitor?

Comment: Since Drupal 8 entity caching is in core. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/597236

Comment: Great! So using what I do is not creating any performance issue? Thanks